# 500 Error after modifying .htaccess to use php7.2 instead of php5.6

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I'm setting up Laravel on a shared hosting server. For debugging purposes, I've created a phpinfo.php file that just contains:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

When I go to https://example.com/phpinfo.php, I would get a page saying the version is 5.6.something. I then went into the Multi-php tool on cPanel to change the version to php7.2, which added this code to the .htaccess file:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

After that happened, going to https://example.com/phpinfo.php gives a 500 error, saying that it also wasn't able to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. I've looked at the logs on cPanel, but they didn't have anything since I changed the version.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: usually 500s are caused by an error. Check your error log and you will see what the server is complaining about. For cPanel, you may have to go in some custom logs to find them.

Comment: Not fixable without real error message. Consult your hosting support if you don't have access to anything but cPanel.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had "php-fpm" disabled. I enabled it and that worked.